# Different large tile and medium tile in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 supporting Live Tiles (the default medium and small). I update the Live Tile using a fairly standard code

```
var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
if (tile == null) return;

var data = new StandardTileData {Title = "some title"};
data.BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Background.png", UriKind.Relative);
data.Count = count;
tile.Update(data);
```

I want to add support for the Large tile but I want to to be different. I do not want to use the count and I want to render some custom text to the images:

```
var data = new StandardTileData {Title = "some title"};
data.BackgroundImage = new Uri("path to a custom rendered image", UriKind.Relative);
data.Count = 0;
```

My question is, how do I determine if my Live tile is Medium (small) or Large make the appropriate update? Or how do I set the tile update to be entirely different for Medium (small) and Large tile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StandardTileData` is the WP7 specific format for tile data. It's WP8 equivalent is 
[`FlipTileData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206971%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which includes separate properties for the different tile sizes:

```
FlipTileData TileData = new FlipTileData()
{
   Title = "[title]",
   BackTitle = "[back of Tile title]",
   BackContent = "[back of medium Tile size content]",
   WideBackContent = "[back of wide Tile size content]",
   Count = [count],
   SmallBackgroundImage = [small Tile size URI],
   BackgroundImage = [front of medium Tile size URI],
   BackBackgroundImage = [back of medium Tile size URI],
   WideBackgroundImage = [front of wide Tile size URI],
   WideBackBackgroundImage = [back of wide Tile size URI],
};
```

See also the WP8 specific docs for tiles. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: close .. I do not want the count for the large tile, just for small and medium

Comment: Unfortunately hiding the count is not supported fro wide tiles, the alternative would be to generate an image which includes it and use that instead.